# autotools with bison and flex sources

Tags: bison, autotools, flex-lexer

I have a C project which includes a flex and a bison source file; the flex file #includes the bison-generated tab.h file.

So I've added AC_PROG_LEX and AC_PROG_YACC to my configure.ac file. But after I've run the autotools and I attempt to make the project, the flex-generated .c file is compiled *before* bison has been run to generate the tab.h file #included by the flex .c file. Hence the compilation fails.

I'm very much an autotools (and stackoverflow!) newbie - do I need to make autotools aware of the flex .o dependency on the bison .tab.h? If so, where would that dependency go - in the Makefile.am containing the project SOURCES list?

TIA
John

Comment: Did you follow the steps [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Yacc-and-Lex.html)? You need to post the relevant parts of `Makefile.am` if you want to get any useful help.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I hadn't spotted that. I haven't digested it yet, but hopefully it will provide the answer; many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell automake that the header file is to be built rather than already provided by you.  Put this in the Makefile.am:

```
BUILT_SOURCES = tab.h
```

Comment: I have the same issue
This answer does not say how can ensure that bison must be executed before flex. In my `Makefile.am` file I have this rule: `pgfs_cmplr_SOURCES = src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.y src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l` and `BUILT_SOURCES = src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.h` but it does not generate any `*.tab.h` file, which is required by `pgfs_cmplr.l` because it `#include` it. I have tried with many names like: `y.tab.h`, `pgfs_cpmlr.tab.h`, `pgfs_cpmlr.h`, etc., I also have tried manually compile (out of autotools) and there it works, so we can know that `*.y` and `*.l` are ok and its an autotools config issue

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can't have the parser and the scanner use the same prefix.

That is,

```
bin_PROGRAM = baz
AM_YFLAGS = -d
BUILT_SOURCES = foo.h
baz_SOURCES = main.c foo.l foo.y
```

will not work, but

```
bin_PROGRAM = baz
AM_YFLAGS = -d
BUILT_SOURCES = bar.h
baz_SOURCES = main.c foo.l bar.y
```

will insure `automake` builds `bar.y` before `foo.l`.

So make sure your scanner and parser use different filenames, and you're good to go.